# Implementation of log4net which writes to SQL DB

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a basic implementation of this that calls a stored procedure which adds a row to a table in a SQL database. However, this implementation has a lot of overhead because it tries to access the database for every log I try to implement (many log calls can occur within one function call). I want to improve this implementation by making it access the database once only when the calling function ends. I also want to make the use of this function nearly identical to using the logger provided by log4net.

Desired Implementation:

```
class Object{
    SQLLogger logger = SQLLogManager.GetLogger("My Object");
    void foo(){
        logger.Info("Info");
        logger.Error("Error");
        logger.Info("Info2");
        //now when the function ends, the logger will access the DB and create 3 rows, disconnects
    }
}
```

Old Implementation:

```
class Object{
    SQLLogger logger = SQLLogManager.GetLogger("My Object");
    void foo(){
        logger.Info("Info");
        //access DB and adds a row, disconnects
        logger.Error("Error");
        //access DB and adds a row, disconnects
        logger.Info("Info2");
        //access DB and adds a row, disconnects
    }
}
```

**Questions:**
How to detect when the function ends (-ish)?
   - Maybe instead I have a container which stores X rows and accesses the db only when container is full or when a timer goes off?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to have log4net easily detect when a function/method.  But log4net does have a bufferSize setting were it will wait until X number of logs are queued and then write them.

<bufferSize value="100" />

Comment: The `bufferSize` option in Log4Net is specifically for this purpose.  Generally you would want "immediate" logging to be done to a file or another stream of some kind, but for database logging you'd want a reasonable buffer depending on the number of log entries you expect per second/minute/etc. in the system.

Comment: Is SQLLogger your own implementation? If so, you must implement this as a strategy within your class.